# Grid layout justify center

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

I want to create a grid layout with grid or flexbox like the images below, if the items are wrapped to new line, ones in the second line must be horizontally centered.
I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```css
.custom-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.content {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-grid">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content">hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: this is what I have]

[image: This is what I want (obviously perfectly centered)]

Comment: can you add a working code snippet? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I've add a snippet

Comment: A snippet (in SO speak) is different than a code block. Look for the button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use wrap and justify-content.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9qwa1r8u/1/

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that space-around isn't quite right. That'll leave a larger center gutter in the second row, no?

Comment: I tried something similar but i don't like using fixed width for my wrapper.

Comment: @isherwood yes, it does.

Comment: @icyDog the fixed width is just there to show the wrapping. It doesn't need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a flex layout like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
.grid  > div {
  flex:0 1 calc(100%/3);
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.content {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background:red;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is ok, but i want to mantain width and margins between items

Comment: @icyDog play with the padding of grid-items